# Stacked Barplot in ggplot2 not displaying correct values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame that conatins percent values that add up to around 48. I want to display these percent values and their corresponding names ("Genus" in the code) in a stacked barplot. I wish for the barplot to reach up to around 48 on the y axis, however it's not doing it. Even if I change the percent values to the absolute values nothing changes. I'm using geom_col(), shouldn't this prevent ggplot from calculating percent values on it's own? Here's the code so far:

```
ggplot(filter1, aes(x = as.factor("M1"), y = rel, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

I excluded the data.frames, hopefully you can still make sense of it.
If I add labels like so

```
ggplot(filter1, aes(x = as.factor("M1"), y = rel, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_label(aes(label = Genus))
```

the labels are displayed in correct positions, see the attatched plots.

I'm totally stumped, I've seen similar codes on google that seem to work like I want my code to work. I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Could you please help me find out what im doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

[image: resulting plot without labels]

[image: resulting plot with labels]

Comment: `position = "fill"` means "scale all added bars to 1", `position = "stack"` would add your bars up to 48. It's still not quite going to work though - your y-axis values for labels are the non-summed identities ('Lamprocystis' at the top). If you're able to give a testable subset of your data (using `dput` or simulated data) that might make it easier to help you find a working solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Andy Baxter's comment, my mistake was to add the `postition = "fill"` argument, which will scale everything to one. Using `position "stack"` instead has brought the desired results.
[image: plot with correct bars]

As Andy correctly pointed out, adding labels via the `geom_label()` function will result in label position that has not been summed up and therefore wrong. I was able to solve this issue myself by using `position_stack()` in the `position` argument which stacked the labels correctly.

Here's the solving code.

```
ggplot(filter1, aes(x = as.factor("M1"), y = rel, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_label(aes(label = Genus), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

And the corresponding plot.[image: correct plot with correct labels]

Thank you very much Andy, that was very helpful!

Comment: Brilliant fix, good work! Make sure you accept your own answer to get the rep, although I think you have to come back after 48 hours to do this :)